# Bootstrap Sidebar toggle active links is not working

Tags: jquery, html

```js
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {

    "use strict";
    e.preventDefault();
        
    
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
     
$("#menu-toggle-2").click(function (e) {
 "use strict";       
         e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
        $('#menu ul').hide();
    });
 
     function initMenu() {
      $('#menu ul').hide();
      $('#menu ul').children('.current').parent().show();
      //$('#menu ul:first').show();
      $('#menu li a').click(
        function() {
          var checkElement = $(this).next();
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            return false;
            }
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            return false;
            }
          }
        );
      }
    $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();
    });
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
 
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="newfeeds.html" id="home" data-toggle="nav-pills"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-stack-1x "></i></span>News Feed</a>
                       <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
                      </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-stack-1x "></i></span> Messages</a>
              
                    </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-equalizer fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Activity</a>
                    <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li><a href="profile.html"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Posts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Recent Activity</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                 <li>
                    <a href="profilesetting.html" id="profilesetting" data-toggle="nav-pills"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Profile Settings</a>
                </li>
                <li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
```

I'm using it in Bootstrap. When I click Profile setting and then go back to News feed it's not working. I guess jquery somewhere wrong. I'm not expert in jquery trying to learn jquery. I have google it but didn't give me the right answer.